# What're the differences between two SDKs

Tags: google-app-engine

I am only just starting on Google App Engine.  From one web page, I was asked to install GoogleCloudSDKInstaller.exe to run some examples (wasn't successful).  On another page, I was asked (have not done so) to install GoogleAppEngine-1.9.15.msi (Google App Engine SDK for Python).

Do I need both?  Can I omit the first, where the App Engine Launcher has an ugly UI, always hangs and have to be shut down manually all the time, and the Cloud SDK Shell once running doesn't respond to Ctrl-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud SDK provides tools to [manage and configure](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) your cloud account. In addition, it's [bundled with other cloud services SDKs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/cloudplatform). If you install the Cloud SDK, you don't need to install the App Engine SDK, it's included. On the other hand, you can install the App Engine SDK only without installing the Cloud SDK.

So basically if you want some cloud configuration tools + all the SDKs bundled together, install the Cloud SDK. If you don't want to use the Cloud SDK, then install the SDKs you want individually.

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying that Google Cloud SDK is a super set of the Google App Engine SDK for Python?

Comment: Yes. The App Engine SDK for Python is included in the Cloud SDK.